# Did GPS turned on when I saw blinking GPS icon on notification bar?

Tags: android, gps

When I turn on GPS with code in my android program, I saw blinking GPS icon in notification bar. Does it mean the GPS has turned on successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0. However, you can change wifi off on programmatically
[Android 4.1.2 How to turn off GPS programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048995/android-4-1-2-how-to-turn-off-gps-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Mean that are looking for a GPS signal, when it stop to Blink you are with a GPS signal.

You might have asked for some request.

Like this:

```
yourLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locationListenerGPS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The blinking gps icon indicates the gps (location provider) is enabled.

You can also call LocationManager.isProviderEnabled() to be sure.

Here's the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html