# Android 4.1.2 How to turn off GPS programmatically

Tags: android, gps, adt

I am trying to switch on GPS by code. The following is the code I've used.

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    context.sendBroadcast(poke);
```

The code executing in OnReceive function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey GIKO check out my answer. You will be able to turn on and turn off GPS using code!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0. However, you can change wifi off on programmatically

Comment: I too was making gps app, but my mind was broken too. I read somewhere that you cant turn on gps above 4.0

Comment: do you have any developer.android.com's link? where exactly they stated this. @RahulGupta

Answer (score 8):

> How to turn off GPS programmatically

The GPS radio will be on so long as:

- It is enabled
- One or more apps are trying to obtain the user's location via GPS

You are welcome to have your app no longer try to obtain the user's location. However, whether the GPS is on is outside of your control.

> I try to use this code. But nothing happening.

That is good, because the security flaw that you are trying to exploit has long been fixed.

Apps cannot enable or disable GPS programmatically, except perhaps on rooted devices. Please allow the user to do that.

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this? Is it possible to hold the ctrl key go to the specific function in the android kernel and make a function similar to it and run the duplicate function to bypass the original function.

Comment: @commonsWare I have seen Google Fit app is turning my GPS on. I am using it on moto G which has Android Lollipop.

Comment: @Ankit: Through `SettingsApi` in the Play Services SDK, you can pop up a dialog to ask the user to enable locations. Beyond that, Google apps tend to be privileged, particularly pre-installed ones, and they can do things that ordinary SDK apps cannot.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);


    }
}
```

**Method1:**

```
 // automatic turn off the gps
    public void turnGPSOff()
    {
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
```

try this if above method doesn't work

**Method 2:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE"); intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Code to turn on GPS on 4.0 and above:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void turnGPSOn(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (! provider.contains("gps"))
    { //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        context.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void turnGPSOff(Context context)
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (provider.contains("gps"))
    { //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        context.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change GPS off on programmatically from versions 4.0 & above. Android guidelines have been changed due to some privacy reasons .