# Unable to disable GPS in Android programmatically

Tags: android, gps

I came to know that we can not disableGPS in Android programmatically for Android versions above 2.3.3, so in my Eclipse I created an app with target sdk version 2.3.3 and also I installed all libraries required for that but still I am not able to disable GPS. I am trying following method.

Also i want to know. in Android 4.x.x when GPS updates is removed, does it automatically disable the GPS?

```
Void stopGPS()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if (provider.contains("gps"))
    { // if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0. However, you can change wifi off on programmatically.

The code which you used was a security flaw. It has long been fixed. Apps cannot enable or disable GPS programmatically, except perhaps on rooted devices.

[Original Source from CommonsWare's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20049556/3243163)

However the same security flaw for GPRS is still working.

Comment: But i want to know in android 4.x.if we remove gps updates does it, automatically disable gps?

Comment: No, It doesn't disable GPS but it stops GPS i.e. removes GPS fetching activity.

Comment: if so then, if GPS stops then consuming battery power is still same or what?

Comment: @user3209703 yes, but not that much like when it uses to fetch the GPS continuously.

Answer (score -2):

```
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Comment: To me this looks like essentially the same code as in the question and no there's no explanation either.