# Switch ON GPS programmatically

Tags: android, gps

I have Explored all the links available for turning on GPS location.
Is It Deprecated now or Still we can make it working ?

Comment: You're not giving any useful information. On which platform ?

Comment: @PercevalFARAMAZ..For Android OS

Comment: i've added the android tag for you, but you should probably explain a bit more in the questions. Or try here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps

Comment: @Spacedman -In simple word I want to switch on GPS on click of a button which is present in my activity.

Comment: You should link to whatever API documentation you have already found. Have you found something saying it is deprecated? Link to it. Or is it just that you cant find **anything**, and are thinking it might be deprecated? Edit your Q.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426144/turning-on-and-off-gps-programmatically-in-android-4-0-and-above


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048995/android-4-1-2-how-to-turn-off-gps-programmatically

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740365/programmatically-turn-on-gps-in-android

I have referred all above links

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating enabled/disabled with on/off.

If the user has GPS disabled, you cannot enable it programmatically, except by directing the user to the appropriate page in the Settings app.

If the user has GPS enabled, you can turn GPS on by using a suitable location API (e.g., `LocationManager`). Android will turn GPS on and off as needed based on what apps are trying to get GPS fixes. But, again, this only works if the user has enabled GPS.